# Do I need to worry about trends in my time series model?

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I am making a model of income for the pension system over 25 years. I have the income as dependent variable and number of workers and average salary as independent. Both income and salary are effected by time trend. As the trend is on both sides do I have to deal with it? And if so what would be the best approach?

I have tried to include time(Income) into my model but I am not sure if that is correct. So currently my model is like this

```r
lm(Income ~ avg_salry + num_workers + time(Income), data = data)
```

I am not sure if I need to remove the trend in this case and if so that my approach is correct.

Comment: Look at the residuals and see if they seem random.

Comment: Unless I am misinterpreting your notation, doesn't including `time(Income)` on the right hand side account for any linear trend?  What then, do you mean by "remove the trend"?  Indeed, which of the two trends are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but my answer is Yes, you absolutely have to. Ignoring trends in both variables is a good way to make a huge mess of things.

And time series, in general, are very tricky. I did data analysis for 30 years, but, if a client wanted a time series analysis, I would tell them to find an expert.

Also, I would  not use lm with time series. The R help files even have a warning against doing so.

Comment: You might guess that the income of a pension system was related to `avg_salry * num_workers * contribution_rate` and that this might be the starting point of your model